# How to remove untracked in git?

Tags: git

iam facing this issue , anyone can help me.

```
PS C:\Users\lenovo12> git status
warning: could not open directory 'Application Data/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Cookies/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Local Settings/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'My Documents/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'NetHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'PrintHood/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Recent/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'SendTo/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Start Menu/': Permission denied
warning: could not open directory 'Templates/': Permission denied
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        .bash_history
        .gitconfig
        .lesshst
        .vscode/
        AppData/
        Box Sync/
        Contacts/
        Desktop/Add User proj/
        Desktop/Box Sync.lnk
        Desktop/CDP Project/cdp-pro/src/components/Registration.jsx
        Desktop/CDP Project/cdp-pro/src/components/SideNav.js
        Desktop/Capture.PNG
        Desktop/Capture1.PNG
        Desktop/E-commerce App/
        Desktop/Employee IT Support Kit.pdf
        Desktop/GitHub Desktop.lnk
        Desktop/KaaS-Dev/
        Desktop/Microsoft Teams.lnk
        Desktop/Music.json
        Desktop/Person 1 - Chrome.lnk
        Desktop/React-New-project/
        Desktop/Typescript_2023.jpg
        Desktop/Udemy Course Completion 
        Desktop/Udemy Course Completion 
        Desktop/Untitled.png
        Desktop/Visual Studio Code.lnk
        Desktop/day1-css/
        Desktop/desktop.ini
        Desktop/git command.txt
        Desktop/git password.txt
        Desktop/github links.txt
        Desktop/hire-buddy/
        Desktop/hirebuddy.json
        Desktop/important.txt
        Desktop/js projects/
        Desktop/lenovo_aknowledgement.pdf
        Desktop/lloyds password.txt
        Desktop/logo.png.png
        Desktop/portfolio/
        Desktop/screenshots/
        Desktop/tax proc.PNG
        Desktop/testing/
        Desktop/video.html
        Desktop/video_files/
        Desktop/work an.PNG
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        IntelGraphicsProfiles/
        Links/
        Music.json
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT
        NTUSER.DAT{a472305d-8e35-11ec-8789-00155d25431a}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{a472305d-8e35-11ec-8789-00155d25431a}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{a472305d-8e35-11ec-8789-00155d25431a}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        OneDrive - Publicis Groupe/
        OneDrive/
        Pictures/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        Videos/
        hirebuddy/
        html pro/
        index.html
        kaas/
        nextproj/
        node_modules/
        ntuser.dat.LOG1
        ntuser.dat.LOG2
        ntuser.ini
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        portfolio
        rts/
        testproject/
```

iam trying to git commands , but no use if any other solution please reach me.

Comment: What do you mean by _"remove untracked"_? That's your personal data. You shouldn't remove it. You shouldn't `git init` in `C:\Users\lenovo12`. Remove the .git folder.

Comment: You appear to have created a git repo and NPM project in your home directory...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+warning%3A+could+not+open+directory+Application+Data+Permission+denied , https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+init+home

Answer (score 1):

Just manually remove the repo (.git directory) and start over in a different new (empty) directory. I hope you don't have any interesting history in the repo yet.